# Proving $\arctan(\mathrm{e}^{-v}) = \text{arccot}(\mathrm{e}^v)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-verification

Is this a correct way to prove that 
$$ \arctan(\mathrm{e}^{-v}) = \text{arccot}(\mathrm{e}^v) $$ 
$$\tan x = \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^v} $$ 
Turn $\tan x$ into $\sin x$ and $\cos x$
$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} =  \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^v}$$
Multiply $\cos x$
$$ \sin x = \frac{\cos x}{\mathrm{e}^v} $$
$$ \mathrm{e}^v \sin x = \cos x$$
$$ \mathrm{e}^v = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$
Multiply by $\mathrm{e}^v$ and divide by $\sin x$
$$ \mathrm{e}^v = \cot x$$
$$\text{arccot}(\mathrm{e}^v) = x$$

Comment: Taking the e-power as it is (replace it by $x$ if you wish), your derivation looks good

Comment: Looks fine to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but a simpler way to do it is to set everything equal to one another
$$\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{e^v} \iff e^v=\mathrm{arccot}(x)$$
$$\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\arccos(x)}=\frac{1}{e^v}\iff e^v=\frac{\arccos(x)}{\arcsin(x)}$$
everything cancels out resulting in that they do equal each other in the set $\{v : v \in \mathbb R\}$ because $\frac{1}{e^v}$ or $e^v$ does not equal zero ever.

Comment: You're abusing the equals sign in the middle of those two lines.  It's not true that $\frac{1}{e^v} = e^{v}$.  What you mean is $\iff$.  And the last line isn't needed.

Comment: @Gil, $\arctan x=y\implies x=\tan y$ but not conversely always

Answer (score 0):

I think it's correct.

Just $$\arctan{x}=\text{arccot}\frac{1}{x}$$ for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You may also use the mean value theorem. Let $f(x)=\arctan (e^x)-\arctan (e^{-x})$, so $f'(x)=\displaystyle \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}-\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}\Longrightarrow f'(x)=\displaystyle \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}-\frac{e^{x}}{1+e^{2x}}=0\Longrightarrow f(x)=$constant by the mean value theorem. If you put $x=0$ you get constant$=0$.